# label incoming emails from a different account in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

Assume I have created a label called "example@university.ac.uk" and I also have that account in my Gmail account, i.e. I can receive and send emails from it.

How do I send all the received emails from that account to the  "example@university.ac.uk" label? I would like them to go directly there and not to have them also on the inbox.
I tried the from option on filters but doesn't do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under **Settings** (click the gear in the top-right corner), **Account**, look under the section titled **Check mail from other accounts (using POP3):**. Next to the account, select **Edit Info.**

[image: account settings]

You should see options to label messages coming into that account with a label. If you check "Archive income messages" the messages will skip the inbox, as the description states.

Alternatively, you can create a filter that does this. Create a filter, and in the "Has the Words" field, use this pattern:

```
(((from:(example@university.ac.uk)) OR (to:(example@university.ac.uk))))
```

This will match all emails to and/or from that email address.